# StringFormat flags : display the whole line

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, string-formatting

the StringFormat flags permits to differently represent a string in a rectangle.

[in this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0300__2D-Graphics/StringFormatFlagsNoClip.htm) was used `string_format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip` one:

[image]

## Question

having

```
txt = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

can I represent this text entirely as a single line (non-clipped and centered).

I mean, I use a default rectangle without knowing what will be the length of the text, but i know where should be the text **center**.

Comment: So you want to squish the text into your rectangle, or just center it and let the text to the left and right that doesn't fit be clipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `StringFormat.Trimming` property is the magic to make this occur, if I understood your question:

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
format.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
e.Graphics.DrawString(text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, format);
```